# Selenium webpage not loading properly

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape university ranking infomation from USNews site. And the problem is when I use selenium to open the webpage, the 'Load More Button' is not working properly. (I think I successfully click it but in the Chrome window opened by webdriver, when I scroll down to the button, is says that 'We're sorry, there was a problem loading the next page of search results'.

I am new to web scrawler and I did a lot of research on this, there are several similar questions but none of those answers helped. I really need some help. Here is my code:

```
driver_path = 'xxx' (chromedriver path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
url2 = 'https://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/rankings'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get(url2)
driver.maximize_window()
count = 1
while True:
    try:
        print(1)
        # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='rankings']/div[3]/button")))
        print(2)
        show_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rankings']/div[3]/button")))
        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(show_more).click().perform()
        print(3)
        # driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='rankings']/div[3]/button").click()
        # print(4)
        # wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='rankings']/div[3]/button")))
        # print(5)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(2)
        if count >=2:
            break
```

Even though I did not write code to close the ad, but I don't think the ad is the problem since when I manually close it and then click the button, it is still not working. Is it the problem with the website?

```
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that there is an anti scraping control in the specific site. It is always recommended to consult the [robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt) file beforehand and check whether scraping is possible on a certain site or not.

In general, this site blocks just the IP (try to go to other pages afterwards, you will see that you will get a 403 error).

In general, however, the approach you used does not seem wrong to me. You can try contacting the site directly to see if the problem can be solved in some other way.